# How i get product id in aroundExcute function?

Tags: magento2, product

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace custom\ScheduleContentNotifier\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ProductApplier;
use custom\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper\Email;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\CatalogStaging\Helper\ReindexPool;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\CacheContext;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Staging\Model\StagingApplierInterface;
use Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager;
use Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface;



class PluginProductApplier
{
    protected $emailHelper;



    /**
     * @var UpdateRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $updateRepository;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $productCollectionResource;

    /**
     * @var ReindexPool
     */
    protected $indexerPool;

    /**
     * @var IndexerRegistry
     */
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var CacheContext
     */
    protected $cacheContext;

    /**
     * @param UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository
     * @param Collection $productResource
     * @param ReindexPool $indexerPool
     * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
     * @param CacheContext $cacheContext
     */

    public function __construct(
        Collection $productResource,
        ReindexPool $indexerPool,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        CacheContext $cacheContext,
        UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository,
        Email $emailHelper,
    ) {
        $this->updateRepository = $updateRepository;
        $this->productCollectionResource = $productResource;
        $this->indexerPool = $indexerPool;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->cacheContext = $cacheContext;
        $this->emailHelper = $emailHelper;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    public function aroundExecute(ProductApplier $subject)
    {  
        $currentVersionId = $this->updateRepository->getVersionMaxIdByTime(strtotime('now'));

        $this->emailHelper->sendEmail();
    }
}
```

Comment: share the code of your di.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you are building a plugin for this method `Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ProductApplier::execute`.

If this is true, then your plugin `aroundExecute` method should looke like this

```
public function aroundExecute(ProductApplier $subject, callable $proceed, array $entityIds) 
{
    ....
}
```

To answer your question, you can get the product ids that are being process from `$entityIds`.
Now to explain a bit the parameters you need to add to your method.

- `ProductApplier $subject` - that's the class instance you are intercepting. You already have this
- `callable $proceed` - this is the original method being intercepted. you can call it anywhere inside your plugin to execute the original code like this `$proceeed($entityIds)`. Not calling this will remove any other plugins you have on this method other than this.
- `$entityIds` - this represents the parameter(s) of the original method you intercepted. So the product ids where content stating is applied

You can get more info on how `around` plugins work, and what parameters they accept from the official documentation: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/#around-methods